# GitLab unable to access Gitolite

Tags: gitlab

I changed in gitlab.yml the address from localhost to a cloud server IP
address & restarted via 'sudo /etc/init.d/gitlab restart'. I can log in
fine but when I create a new project I get:

`GitLab was unable to access your Gitolite system`

Has anyone come across this? The web is full of the same question (I'm
getting `ERROR -> Pull error -> unable to clone gitolite-admin repo` in
the logs) but no answers.

I've stopped Gitlab, cleared /tmp but the problem still persists.

Comment: Which gitlab version is this? Gitlab doesn't use gitolite since gitlab 5.x.

Comment: I didn't know that. Maybe I should just go ahead & upgrade (I'm using 4). Running `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production --trace` just comes back with
`rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'gitlab:check'` I'll upgrade & see if that solves the problem. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Considering [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/) isn't using [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) since 5.x (see "[GitLab Without Gitolite](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-without-gitolite/)"), the first things to try is upgrade/[install the latest version](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq#installation).

The [lastest releases are listed here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/releases).